# How to write LHS in maths documents?

Tags: math-mode

In a maths document I am writing on Overleaf, I want to write 'LHS' as part of a proof for something, standing for Left Hand Side, and I want it contained within the dollar signs. Do you know how to do that? Note: I don't want it in italics, as it automatically appears if I simply type it within the dollar signs.

Thank you.

Comment: either use `\mathrm{LHS}` or `\newcommand\LHS{\mathrm{LHS}}` in preamble and then use `\LHS` in math

Comment: @daleif thanks a lot for that, it works excellently :)

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Davislor thank you :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables like this can be written as either `\mathrm{LHS}` if you have a just a few. If used often it is better to add

```
\newcommand\LHS{\mathrm{LHS}}
```

to your preamble and then use `\LHS` in math.

Comment: Can I use that \newcommand function to make any new command for anything I want?

Comment: As long as the macro name doesn't already exist. Note that youight want to learn `\DeclareMathOperator` as well (see the manual for `amsmath`) and some features from the `mathtools` package.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the suggestions. What do you mean by macro again? I've forgotten.

Comment: Here `\LHS` is a macro, a very simple one as its replacement is `\mathrm{LHS}`.

Comment: So a macro is an operation of some sort, like \sum, \prod, \int and all the rest?

Comment: Well that depends on how you look at ot. LaTeX is a macro expansion "language" it takes a little getting used to. One could argue that `\alpha` is a macro, it just expands (evaluates) to the math symbol alpha. A more interesting macro could be `\section{Title}` which expands to lots of stuff which then xpands to lots of other stuff.